Text Blurring Issue with react-tooltip and react-modal when using opacity/transform animations in Chrome
I am working on a project using two libraries: react-modal and react-tooltip.
Goal:
I want to create a reusable React component that provides a simple modal window, which renders its children.
Problem:
When tooltips are rendered inside the modal, a slide-in animation causes a text blurring issue in Chrome. The animation looks like this:
@keyframes slideIn {
  from {
    transform: translate(-50%, -30%);
    opacity: 0;
  }
  to {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

Details:

The issue only occurs in Chrome; Firefox renders sharp text
The flickering / blurring happens when hovering over an element in the modal that triggers a tooltip to show.
It seems like the opacity in the animation is required to cause the issue
Commenting out the animation line in the CSS fixes the issue (text is sharp)

Attempted Solutions:
I tried several CSS fixes without success. The only working solution was moving the tooltip outside of the modal's DOM tree into the root element, as suggested by the react-tooltip troubleshooting documentation. However, I believe tooltips should reside within their respective components for better abstraction. I might be completely wrong on this and how I'm rendering these tooltips.
Reproduction:
Here is a CodeSandbox demonstrating the issue.
Steps:

Open the modal
Hover over the box which triggers the tooltip (hover over and away repeatedly to enhance effect)
Observe text blurring on Chrome
See comments in styles.css



I ended up actually moving my tooltip to sit in my App.tsx under the root element. With react-tooltip you can pass data-tooltip-html attribute for custom HTML rendering. Use renderToStaticMarkup to convert JSX to html (don't forget to memo this as this function isn't super cheap). This is working well enough for me, I just wish I didn't spend 8+ hours debugging the above issue first.
